# Cambodian keyboard for Windows and Linux?

Tags: python

Before I created http://khmerlc.org/khmerkeyweb/ with javascript that allow user input 
cambodia unicode user can switch from English to khmer(cambodia)

I am going to build an application called khmerkey for desktop (both can run window,linux).
I will use python.

the User interface it's very  simple, just:
With two options(allow user to switch from khmer to english) or access switch by shortcut key.

Anybody know any informations related to my goal.
Is it easy to deploy it with python ( some tips)?

Reference:

Unicode_chart_Khmer

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Khmer
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1780.pdf
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there something wrong with the standard keyboard switchers built into Windows, GNOME and KDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooking keys and sendkeys is different way for Windows and Linux, so you have to do it seperately.

In Windows, you can use combination of [PyHook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [SendKeys](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/)

For Linux, I have no idea now, I will update this when I found something.